# Hikari connection pool issue with sybase

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sybase, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

I have a java spring boot application which does bulk insert data to sybase using Spring JDBC driver . I am using Sybase JDBC driver and  uses DriverManagerDataSource and HikariConnectionPool to do the bulk insert. The Datasource creation goes fine  and but  when i try to creat the HikariConnectionPool its giving error   Connection Closed error.  Below is the code .As you see i am doing an explicit call to see if connecton is closed and it returns false. I am not ble to understand what i am missing here. TIA for any suggestions.

**SOURCE CODE**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public class SpringJDBCLocalConfiguration {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringJDBCLocalConfiguration.class);


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {


        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(){{
            setDriverClassName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver");
            setUrl("url");
            setUsername("username");
            setPassword("passwd");         
        }};;

        try {
            Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            logger.info("SpringJDBCLocalConfiguration conn "+conn);
            logger.info("SpringJDBCLocalConfiguration conn isClosed "+conn.isClosed());

        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            logger.error("SpringJDBCLocalConfiguration error getting connection in SpringJDBCLocalConfiguration "+exc);
        }

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig() {{
            setDataSource(dataSource);
            setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        }};

        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return hikariDataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());        
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

**ERROR STACK TRACE**

```
[ main] c.j.a.w.e.d.SpringJDBCLocalConfiguration : inside SpringJDBCLocalConfiguration.dataSource method flushStrategy
[ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig : sybase-pool - idleTimeout is close to or more than maxLifetime, disabling it.
[ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : sybase-pool - Starting...
[ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase : sybase-pool - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
[ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : sybase-pool - Exception during pool initialization.
 java.sql.SQLException: JZ0C0: Connection is already closed.
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:779) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.checkConnection(SybConnection.java:4010) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.close(SybStatement.java:744) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.close(SybStatement.java:719) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.MdaManager.loadMetaData(MdaManager.java:573) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.MdaManager.<init>(MdaManager.java:188) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.MdaManager.<init>(MdaManager.java:171) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.checkMDA(SybConnection.java:4155) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getMDA(SybConnection.java:3685) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.setOption(Tds.java:1829) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.setReadOnly(SybConnection.java:2586) ~[jconn4-7.07-27307.jar!/:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:409) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:370) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was  application was running in cloud and able to establish the database connection but  seems firewall  killing the connection so at the time of connection pool creation no active connections were found causing this error. I tried explicitly whitelisting the ip address and port but still same issue,but the root cause is the firewall blocking connection.

Comment: Have the same issues with HikariCP and jconnect driver. Tried a different versions of jconn4.jar without success. Looks like database or firewall drops connections, but stopping firewalls on the both side (client and server) -  issues occurs again